# How to create typealias for completion handlers with named arguments

Tags: ios, swift, type-alias

What I have so far is this:

1. I've defined `typealias` completion handler

   ```
   typealias UserCompletionHandler = (_ object: User?, _ error: ApiError?) -> Void
   ```
2. And I've created a service function that is using this typealias

   ```
   func login(email: String, password: String, completion: UserCompletionHandler) {
      // ...
      // this part here handles API call and parsing logic
      // ...

      completion(user, nil)
   }
   ```

What I want to achieve is to have more readable completion callback with parameters by introducing named arguments. Idea is to end up with this:

```
   completion(object: user, error: nil)
```

Or even better to make error parameter optional, so I can just call

```
   completion(object: user)
```

Issue is that I can't find a way to change `typealias` definition to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible. You can find the explanation behind this choice in the swift evolution proposal: [0111-remove-arg-label-type-significance.md](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0111-remove-arg-label-type-significance.md)

> Function types may only be defined in terms of the types of the formal parameters and the return value.
> Writing out a function type containing argument labels will be prohibited

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this answer is ideal, but you could use a tuple as your input argument:

```
typealias UserCompletionHandler = ((object: User?, error: ApiError?)) -> Void
```

and the usage would look like this:

```
completion((object: user, error: nil))
```

Comment: I like this approach. It does have extra braces around it, but it does give cleaner naming and improves readability of the handler usage. Thanks Edward!